# How to avoid error-message during the execution of a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling

I need to write a bash-script  which will find all files with name `string.h` on the computer and copy them to some folder. My code is here:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo find / -type f -name "string.h" -exec cp {} $HOME/MyDocuments
```

But during the execution of the script, I get error-messages on my console terminal "permission denied". Please, told me, how I can avoid getting this message? Console terminal must be clear.

Comment: Not an answer, but you lack `\;` at the end of the line, and if several files are called `string.h` they will all overwrite each other in the target directory.

Comment: Getting a "Permission denied" while root is somewhat interesting in itself. (NFS and SELinux or such come to mind)

Comment: Is `$HOME/MyDocuments` an existing directory, or are you expecting your script to create it?

Answer (score 0):

The errors "permission denied" are "ok" if your find try to travel in directories where your user have no read-permission or the `cp` in your line try to write to a directory you have no access to. You can suppress them with redirecting stderr

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo find / -type f -name "string.h" -exec cp {} $HOME/MyDocuments \; 2>/dev/null
```

The pattern `2>/dev/null` means to send all errors to "nowhere" instead of standard-error.

But sending error messages to `/dev/null` will not solve the error that your command will not have permission to read or to write.

Comment: One of the issues here is that the OP is running `find` with `sudo`.  It is unclear what produces the errors.

Comment: That is right. Maybe there is an immutable-flag on one of the directories (maybe the `$HOME/MyDocuments`.  Maybe we can check this with the output of `lsattr -d`for the directory in question.

Comment: Another issue here is that if there's more than a single matching file on your system, only the last one will be present in 'MyDocuments' after running that command.